# MySQL FROM multiple tables LEFT JOIN Unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: php, mysql, silverstripe

I've got an interesting query that I seem to be having trouble with.

I need to select data from several tables and join on an additional table that has a column that may not be present on the other tables.

I've tried a couple of angles on this.  Here's the first one:

```
SELECT SiteTree.*, Page.*, AlbumItem.*, Album.*
FROM SiteTree, AlbumItem, Album
LEFT JOIN Page ON SiteTree.ID = Page.ID
```

Throws this: #1054 - Unknown column 'SiteTree.ID' in 'on clause', presumebly because when it gets to trying to join when selecting from the Album table there is no SiteTree.ID column.

I've also tried this:

```
SELECT SiteTree.*, Page.*, AlbumItem.*, Album.*
FROM SiteTree LEFT JOIN Page ON SiteTree.ID = Page.ID, AlbumItem, Album
```

Which returns about 20 Rows and I know there should only be 2 based on the where clause.  Infact there about 10 copies of each result row

There where clause is as follows:

```
WHERE (
    (
        AlbumItem.ClassName = 'AlbumItem' OR 
        Album.ClassName = 'Album' OR 
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'Page' OR 
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'HomePage' OR 
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'NewsCategory' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'NewsArticle' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'CartPage' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'Product' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'ProductGroup' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'MemberProfilePage' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'SubscriptionPage' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'ErrorPage' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'RedirectorPage' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'VirtualPage' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'UserDefinedForm' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'CheckoutPage' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'OrderConfirmationPage' OR
        SiteTree.ClassName = 'TagPage'
    ) AND (
       INSTR(Page.Tags,'x') OR
       INSTR(AlbumItem.Tags,'x') OR
       INSTR(Album.Tags,'x')
    )
)
```

Reducing the query to this produces the correct result, but it wont work for the other tables as well:

```
SELECT SiteTree.*, Page.*
FROM SiteTree
LEFT JOIN Page ON SiteTree.ID = Page.ID
```

What I need to know is if what I am trying to doing is possible without resorting to unions?

Comment: Reading this [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=5) explains why I get 20 results for my from clause `FROM SiteTree LEFT JOIN Page ON SiteTree.ID = Page.ID, AlbumItem , Album `.  The question is now seems to be how do I filter the cartesian product down to producing one combined row for each match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I now have a working query.

To put things in perspective I was building a taggable module in SilverStripe.  The ORM in SilverStripe allows for extensions to be added on to multiple DataObjects which may have unique sets of tables that don't share common columns to perform a `JOIN` with an `ON` clause.

I was trying to work wuith the limitations of the `SQLQuery` object when generating a query.  The SQLQuery object in SilverStripe doesn't support `UNION` so I was hoping that I wouldn't have to generate a full raw SQL query.  It seems as though there is no way to avoid the production of a cartesian product with out using a `UNION`.

So I ended up making a thin wrapper for PDO and using a `UNION` based query as shown below.  It's automatically generated in a script that walks the object graph to find all relevant tables so its slightly more verbose than it would be if i had written it manually.  Also it should use a regex match so the matching is more accurate, but at this point in time I was more concerned with the query producing some usable output:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS SiteTree.ClassName, SiteTree.ID
FROM SiteTree LEFT JOIN Page ON SiteTree.ID = Page.ID
WHERE (
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'Page' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'HomePage' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'NewsCategory' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'NewsArticle' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'GalleryPage' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'CartPage' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'Product' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'ProductGroup' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'MemberProfilePage' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'SubscriptionPage' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'ErrorPage' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'RedirectorPage' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'VirtualPage' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'UserDefinedForm' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'CheckoutPage' OR 
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'OrderConfirmationPage' OR
    SiteTree.ClassName = 'TagPage'
) AND (
    INSTR(Page.Tags,'x')
)

UNION ALL

SELECT AlbumItem.ClassName, AlbumItem.ID
FROM AlbumItem
WHERE (AlbumItem.ClassName = 'AlbumItem') AND (INSTR(AlbumItem.Tags,'x'))

UNION ALL

SELECT Album.ClassName, Album.ID
FROM Album
WHERE (Album.ClassName = 'Album') AND (INSTR(Album.Tags,'x'))

LIMIT 0,40
```

Answer (score 1):

The lack of actual join criteria for `AlbumItem` and `Album` make for a (couple) full outer join / cross join issues.  You should join those two tables in properly.  Otherwise you'll get at least one record for each of those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a column named `ID` in the `SiteTree` table?  Given the error message, there isn't.  Fix this so you have it referencing a column that actually exists in your table.

Also, why are you doing `ANSI JOIN`s (i.e. the use of ,) ... you should be `INNER JOIN`s because otherwise you will not get what you expect.

Comment: _Is there a column named ID in the SiteTree table?_

Yes there is.  

_Also, why are you doing ANSI JOINs (i.e. the use of ,) ... you should be INNER JOINs because otherwise you will not get what you expect._

`FROM SiteTree LEFT JOIN Page ON SiteTree.ID = Page.ID INNER JOIN AlbumItem INNER JOIN Album`

produces the same result as

`FROM SiteTree LEFT JOIN Page ON SiteTree.ID = Page.ID, AlbumItem , Album`

Comment: You should always join `ON` something.  Not leave it up to a `CROSS JOIN` to fill in for you.  Can you please show your table structures.

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing to join `Album` or `AlbumItem` on to, i.e they dont share any common key with the SiteTree Table.  The purpose was more to try make a single query for the presence of a given key across multiple tables without doing a union.  I understand that the `,` is creating a cartesian product of various combinations - is there away that can be controlled or am I better off using a union?

Comment: If they don't relate to anything in the query, then they don't belong in the query ... if you need that information I would either add in a second query for it, or a `UNION` ... but even with the `UNION`, you are combining two distinct record sets which mean different things.